# How much time does it take for medical advances to be used in practice?

Tags: research

Is there any research/study/survey/... that tried to assess the time elapsed between the publication of medical advances and when they start to be used in practice?

Answer (score 3):

Title of this publication speaks it all: [The answer is 17 years, what is the question: understanding time lags in translational research](http://jrs.sagepub.com/content/104/12/510.full) (2011). Some quotes:

> This process of conversion of basic science to patient benefit is often called ‘**translation**’
>
> Using different endpoints, different domains and different approaches,
>   Balas and Bohen and Grant et al. both estimate the time lag in
>   health research being 17 years. Wratschko also suggested 17 years as
>   the highest limit for the time taken from drug discovery to
>   commercialization.

From [Making the Leap: the Translation of Innovative Surgical Devices From the Laboratory to the Operating Room (2016)](http://journals.lww.com/annalsofsurgery/Abstract/2016/06000/Making_the_Leap___the_Translation_of_Innovative.12.aspx):

> Innovative surgical devices have preceded many of the major advances
>   in surgical practice. However, the process by which devices arising
>   from academia find their way to translation remains poorly understood.
>   (...) The probability of a [first-in-human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-in-man_study) at 10 years was 9.8%.

From [An overview of recommendations and translational milestones for genomic tests in cancer](http://www.nature.com/gim/journal/v17/n6/abs/gim2014133a.html) (2015):

> The median time from discovery to recommendation statement was 14.7
>   years.

There are people trying to lower those lag times, see for example [Faster by a power of 10: a PLAN for accelerating national adoption of evidence-based practices](http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/25880494) (2015):

> We propose an ambitious goal: to increase the speed of adoption of
>   evidence-based practices by a power of 10, from 17 years to 1.7 years,
>   and present a 4-step PLAN to achieve this.

So maybe in the future things will be better.